# First image doesn't load in IE 8 (Galleria Javascript Photo Album)

Tags: javascript, firefox, internet-explorer-8, galleria

I'm trying to use the Galleria javascript photo album and it works great on Safari and Chrome. When I load the site in Firefox or IE though, the first image doesn't load. If I click the next arrow my images will all load fine.

Here is a link to the site in question.

http://fredandrandall.com/MasterMachine/site/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if Galleria.log() is buggy. Remove those 2 lines :

```
Galleria.log(this) // the gallery instance
Galleria.log(options) // the gallery options
```

Comment: This should be fixed in the latest 1.2.5 version